# android-ndk-profiler undefined reference to monstartup and moncleanup

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, gprof

I am attempting to compile an Android NDK library to use [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler) for profiling.

In `Audio.h`, I have:

```
extern "C" {
    void monstartup(char const*);
    void moncleanup();
}
```

In `Audio.cpp`, I have:

```
#include "Audio.h"
com_example_native_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    // Start profiling
    monstartup("libDMAudiolib.so");
    ...
}
```

I am compiling with

```
ndk-build NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/ndk_modules
```

And the exact compilation error I am getting is

```
Path/to/Audio.cpp:136: error: undefined reference to 'monstartup'
```

Are there any android ndk gurus out there who can tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `monstartup` isn't getting linked in (that looks like a linker error, not a compiler error).

Make sure your `Android.mk` has the additions shown on the [Usage page](https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage), particularly the `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` directive.

Comment: It has the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES directive, and I've tried using the directive from the usage page (`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler`) as well as the directive with an absolute path (`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := /cygdrive/c/ndk_modules/android-ndk-profiler`). No effect.

Comment: Complex projects may have more than one Android.mk, if that is your case the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES variable must be set inside Android.mk file for the library you're profiling. (At least that solved it for me)

Answer (score 1):

`ndk-build` does not work well with cygwin. Please use `C:/ndk-modules` and similar notation in your scripts.

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler
```

is correct, but it requires that your `Andorid.mk` includes something like

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := c:/ndk-modules/android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_MODULE := android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libandprof.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

(see *http://android-ndk-profiler.googlecode.com/svn-history/r11/wiki/Usage.wiki*)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it was due to LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES being in the wrong place in the Android.mk file. In particular, it had to be before the line "include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)".